# Reflection through affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, reflection

> I want to find the affine map of the reflection through the subspace $U\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ defined by the equation $$2x-y+z=1.$$

I did what I deemed to be sensible and would like to verify whether it's correct or contains errors:

At first I described the subspace with parameters: $$U=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\ \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R.$$

Now I computed the reflection through the parallel subset $U_0$ through the origin $$U_0=\lambda\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}+\mu\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\ \lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R.$$ using the fact that the two vectors must be eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$ and that their cross product must be an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$. I ended up with $$A=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&-2\\2&2&1\\-2&1&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now I assume that the reflection $f$ through $U$ is of the form $f(x)=Ax+t$ for some $t\in\mathbb R^3$ and since for $v=(0,0,1)^T\in U$ we have $f(v)=v$ I can just plug it into $f$ which yields $t$ to be $$t=\frac{1}{3}(2,-1,1)^T.$$ To sum it up the reflection $f$ through $U$ must be $$f(x)=Ax+t=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&-2\\2&2&1\\-2&1&2\end{pmatrix}+\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Are my thoughts correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me. There’s a simpler way to arrive at $A$, however.

Following a standard derivation, observe that a reflection through $U_0$ reverses the component of a vector $\mathbf v$ that’s orthogonal to this subspace. I.e., if you decompose $\mathbf v$ into its components $\mathbf v_\parallel+\mathbf v_\perp$ in $U_0$ and $U_0^\perp$, respectively, then its reflection through $U_0$ is $\mathbf v_\parallel-\mathbf v_\perp$. (This is equivalent to your statement about the eigenvectors of this reflection.) However, $\mathbf v_\parallel = \mathbf v-\mathbf v_\perp$, so the reflection can also be written as $\mathbf v-2\mathbf v_\perp$, reducing the problem to one of computing the matrix for projection onto $U_0^\perp$.

From the equation of $U$ we know that $U_0^\perp$ is spanned by $\mathbf n = (2,-1,1)^T$, so you just need to find the matrix for projection onto this single vector. Using the fact that $\mathbf v^T\mathbf n$ is a scalar, hence commutes with any matrix, and regrouping, $$A\mathbf v = \mathbf v - 2{\mathbf v^T\mathbf n\over\mathbf n^T\mathbf n}\mathbf n = \left(I-2{\mathbf n\mathbf n^T\over\mathbf n^T\mathbf n}\right)\mathbf v.$$

Comment: Yes, I've stumbled upon this "householder transformation" once. But in the lecture we haven't arrived yet at the inner product so we can't really make use of words like "orthogonal" etc.
But thanks for checking my ideas!

Comment: @RedLantern Well, you can at least avoid computing the cross product of the two basis vectors for $U_0$ since you already know an eigenvector of $-1$. I’m curious, though: how does one even define reflection without some (perhaps tacit) notion of orthogonality?

Comment: A matrix $A$ satisfying $A^T A=I$ and having determinant $-1$ is called a reflection. But yeah... it's basically just leaving out the word orthogonality.